# How can I use Processing to make a GUI that sends data to Arduino and receives data back to display in the GUI?

Tags: user-interface, arduino, processing

I have a Processing GUI where I have Five different inputs a person types in. Once a button is pressed, those inputs should be sent to the Arduino code where they will be read in and used as integer values for the program. The Arduino should then send five new data points over to Processing where they will be displayed in the GUI. My issue is that I'm pretty sure the Arduino is not getting the inputs the GUI is supposed to send and I am not sure if I have coded both my programs correctly in-order to receive data from the Arduino. I tried to use code from similar programs and adapt it to this, but I must have gone wrong somewhere.

I coded Processing so that the user inputs are sent to Arduino when a button is pressed, but this seems to break the serialEvent and I am not sure how to get both to work correctly or how to make sure that Arduino received the inputs correctly. Here is my code for both programs:

Processing:

```
import controlP5.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
int[] serialInArray = new int[5];
int serialCount = 0;
boolean firstContact = false;

ControlP5 cp5;

String[] inputfieldNames = {"Hopper Temp. Input (°C)", "Hopper Connector Temp. Input (°C)", "CUE Connector Temp. Input (°C)", "CUE Temp. Input (°C)", "Flowrate Input (mm³/s)"};
Textfield hopperTemp;
Textfield hopperconnectorTemp;
Textfield CUEconnectorTemp;
Textfield CUETemp;
Textfield flowrateInput;

String[] currentfieldNames = {"HOPPER PADS ARE OFF", "HOPPER CONNECTOR PADS ARE OFF", "CUE CONNECTOR PADS ARE OFF", "CUE PADS ARE OFF", "MOTOR IS OFF"};
Textarea currenthopperTempreadings;
Textarea currenthopperconnectorTempreadings;
Textarea currentCUEconnectorTempreadings;
Textarea currentCUETempreadings;
Textarea currentflowratereadings;

String[] actualfieldNames = {"HOPPER PADS ARE ACTUALLY OFF", "HOPPER CONNECTOR PADS ARE ACTUALLY OFF", "CUE CONNECTOR PADS ARE ACTUALLY OFF", "CUE PADS ARE ACTUALLY OFF", "MOTOR IS ACTUALLY OFF"};
Textarea hopperTempreadings;
Textarea hopperconnectorTempreadings;
Textarea CUEconnectorTempreadings;
Textarea CUETempreadings;
Textarea flowratereadings;

String[] currentfieldLabels = {"HOPPER TEMP. SETTING (°C)", "HOPPER CONNECTOR TEMP. SETTING (°C)", "CUE CONNECTOR TEMP. SETTING (°C)", "CUE TEMP. SETTING (°C)", "FLOWRATE SETTING (mm³/s)"};
String[] actualfieldLabels = {"ACTUAL HOPPER TEMP. (°C)", "ACTUAL HOPPER CONNECTOR TEMP. (°C)", "ACTUAL CUE CONNECTOR TEMP. (°C)", "ACTUAL CUE TEMP. (°C)", "ACTUAL FLOWRATE (mm³/s)"};

PFont font1;
PFont font2;

int hopperHeating;
int hopperconnectorHeating;
int CUEconnectorHeating;
int CUEHeating;
int motorspeed;

String hopperHeatingstring;
String hopperconnectorHeatingstring;
String CUEconnectorHeatingstring;
String CUEHeatingstring;
String motorspeedstring;

int actualhopperHeating;
int actualhopperconnectorHeating;
int actualCUEconnectorHeating;
int actualCUEHeating;
int actualmotorspeed;

String actualhopperHeatingstring;
String actualhopperconnectorHeatingstring;
String actualCUEconnectorHeatingstring;
String actualCUEHeatingstring;
String actualmotorspeedstring;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup() {
  size(1400,700);
  
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);  //i have connected arduino to com3
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');

  font1 = createFont("arial",20);
  font2 = createFont("arial",40);

  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  int y1 = 60;
  int y2 = 60;
  int y3 = 105;
  int y4 = 60;
  int y5 = 105;
  int y6 = 560;
  int x1 = 20;
  int x2 = 480;
  int x3 = 970;
  int x4 = 1270;
  int h = 40;
  int l1 = 200;
  int l2 = 400;
  int spacing = 100;
  int bd = 100;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  hopperTemp = cp5.addTextfield(inputfieldNames[0])
       .setPosition(x1,y1)
       .setSize(l1,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setFocus(true)
       .setColor(color(255,255,255))
       ;
     y1 += spacing;
     
  hopperconnectorTemp = cp5.addTextfield(inputfieldNames[1])
       .setPosition(x1,y1)
       .setSize(l1,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setFocus(true)
       .setColor(color(255,255,255))
       ;
     y1 += spacing;
     
  CUEconnectorTemp = cp5.addTextfield(inputfieldNames[2])
       .setPosition(x1,y1)
       .setSize(l1,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setFocus(true)
       .setColor(color(255,255,255))
       ;
     y1 += spacing;
     
  CUETemp = cp5.addTextfield(inputfieldNames[3])
       .setPosition(x1,y1)
       .setSize(l1,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setFocus(true)
       .setColor(color(255,255,255))
       ;
     y1 += spacing;
     
  flowrateInput = cp5.addTextfield(inputfieldNames[4])
       .setPosition(x1,y1)
       .setSize(l1,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setFocus(true)
       .setColor(color(255,255,255))
       ;
     y1 += spacing;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
currenthopperTempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(currentfieldNames[0])
       .setPosition(x2,y2)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(currentfieldNames[0])
       ;
     y2 += spacing;
     
currenthopperconnectorTempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(currentfieldNames[1])
       .setPosition(x2,y2)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(currentfieldNames[1])
       ;
     y2 += spacing;
     
currentCUEconnectorTempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(currentfieldNames[2])
       .setPosition(x2,y2)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(currentfieldNames[2])
       ;
     y2 += spacing;

currentCUETempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(currentfieldNames[3])
       .setPosition(x2,y2)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(currentfieldNames[3])
       ;
     y2 += spacing;
     
currentflowratereadings = cp5.addTextarea(currentfieldNames[4])
       .setPosition(x2,y2)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(currentfieldNames[4])
       ;
     y2 += spacing;
  
    for(String currentoutputlabel: currentfieldLabels){
    cp5.addTextlabel(currentoutputlabel)
       .setText(currentoutputlabel)
       .setPosition(x2,y3)
       .setColor(color(255,255,255))
       .setFont(font1)
       ;

       ;
     y3 += spacing;
  }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
hopperTempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(actualfieldNames[0])
       .setPosition(x3,y4)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(actualfieldNames[0])
       ;
     y4 += spacing;
     
hopperconnectorTempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(actualfieldNames[1])
       .setPosition(x3,y4)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(actualfieldNames[1])
       ;
     y4 += spacing;
     
CUEconnectorTempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(actualfieldNames[2])
       .setPosition(x3,y4)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(actualfieldNames[2])
       ;
     y4 += spacing;

CUETempreadings = cp5.addTextarea(actualfieldNames[3])
       .setPosition(x3,y4)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(actualfieldNames[3])
       ;
     y4 += spacing;
     
flowratereadings = cp5.addTextarea(actualfieldNames[4])
       .setPosition(x3,y4)
       .setSize(l2,h)
       .setFont(font1)
       .setLineHeight(14)
       .setColor(color(128))
       .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
       .setColorForeground(color(255,100))
       .setText(actualfieldNames[4])
       ;
     y4 += spacing;
  
    for(String actualoutputlabel: actualfieldLabels){
    cp5.addTextlabel(actualoutputlabel)
       .setText(actualoutputlabel)
       .setPosition(x3,y5)
       .setColor(color(255,255,255))
       .setFont(font1)
       ;

       ;
     y5 += spacing;
  }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cp5.addBang("SUBMIT")
      .setPosition(x1,y6)
      .setSize(bd, bd)
      .getCaptionLabel().align(ControlP5.CENTER, ControlP5.CENTER)
     ;
     
    cp5.addBang("STOP")
      .setPosition(x4,y6)
      .setSize(bd,bd)
      .setColorForeground(color(255,0,0))
      .getCaptionLabel().align(ControlP5.CENTER, ControlP5.CENTER)
     ;
     
    cp5.getController("SUBMIT")
      .getCaptionLabel()
      .setFont(font1)
      .setSize(20)
     ;
     
    cp5.getController("STOP")
      .getCaptionLabel()
      .setFont(font1)
      .setSize(20)
     ;

  textFont(font1);
}

void draw() {
  background(0,0,0);
//  background(224,237,252);

  //lets give title to our window
  fill(222, 242, 250);          
  textFont(font2);
  text("CUE CONTROL", 570, 40);
}

void SUBMIT() {
  hopperHeatingstring = cp5.get(Textfield.class, inputfieldNames[0]).getText();
  hopperHeating = int(hopperHeatingstring);
  //myPort.write(hopperHeating);
  myPort.write(hopperHeatingstring);
  
  hopperconnectorHeatingstring = cp5.get(Textfield.class, inputfieldNames[1]).getText();
  hopperconnectorHeating = int(hopperconnectorHeatingstring);
  //myPort.write(hopperconnectorHeating);
  myPort.write(hopperconnectorHeatingstring);
  
  CUEconnectorHeatingstring = cp5.get(Textfield.class, inputfieldNames[2]).getText();
  CUEconnectorHeating = int(CUEconnectorHeatingstring);
  //myPort.write(CUEconnectorHeating);
  myPort.write(CUEconnectorHeatingstring);
  
  CUEHeatingstring = cp5.get(Textfield.class, inputfieldNames[3]).getText();
  CUEHeating = int(CUEHeatingstring);
  //myPort.write(CUEHeating);
  myPort.write(CUEHeatingstring);
  
  motorspeedstring = cp5.get(Textfield.class, inputfieldNames[4]).getText();
  motorspeed = int(motorspeedstring);
  //myPort.write(motorspeed);
  myPort.write(motorspeedstring);
  
  println(hopperHeatingstring);
  println(hopperconnectorHeatingstring);
  println(CUEconnectorHeatingstring);
  println(CUEHeatingstring);
  println(motorspeedstring);
  
  currenthopperTempreadings.setText(hopperHeatingstring);
  currenthopperconnectorTempreadings.setText(hopperconnectorHeatingstring);
  currentCUEconnectorTempreadings.setText(CUEconnectorHeatingstring);
  currentCUETempreadings.setText(CUEHeatingstring);
  currentflowratereadings.setText(motorspeedstring);
  
}

void STOP() {
  motorspeed = 0;
  hopperHeating = 0;
  hopperconnectorHeating = 0;
  CUEconnectorHeating = 0;
  CUEHeating = 0; 
  myPort.write(hopperHeating);
  myPort.write(hopperconnectorHeating);
  myPort.write(CUEconnectorHeating);
  myPort.write(CUEHeating);
  myPort.write(motorspeed);
  
  String estop = "The emergency stop button was pressed. System set to 0";
  currenthopperTempreadings.setText(estop);
  currenthopperconnectorTempreadings.setText(estop);
  currentCUEconnectorTempreadings.setText(estop);
  currentCUETempreadings.setText(estop);
  currentflowratereadings.setText(estop);
  
  hopperTempreadings.setText(estop);
  hopperconnectorTempreadings.setText(estop);
  CUEconnectorTempreadings.setText(estop);
  CUETempreadings.setText(estop);
  flowratereadings.setText(estop);
  
}

  void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
    // read a byte from the serial port:
    int inByte = myPort.read();
    
    println("we're here");
    // if this is the first byte received, and it's an A, clear the serial
    // buffer and note that you've had first contact from the microcontroller.
    // Otherwise, add the incoming byte to the array:
    if (firstContact == false) {
      if (inByte == 'A') {
        myPort.clear();          // clear the serial port buffer
        firstContact = true;     // you've had first contact from the microcontroller
        myPort.write('A');       // ask for more
      }
    }
    else {
      // Add the latest byte from the serial port to array:
      serialInArray[serialCount] = inByte;
      serialCount++;

      // If we have 5 bytes:
      if (serialCount > 4 ) {
        actualhopperHeating = serialInArray[0];
        actualhopperconnectorHeating = serialInArray[1];
        actualCUEconnectorHeating = serialInArray[2];
        actualCUEHeating = serialInArray[3];
        actualmotorspeed = serialInArray[4];
        
        actualhopperHeatingstring = str(actualhopperHeating);
        actualhopperconnectorHeatingstring = str(actualhopperconnectorHeating);
        actualCUEconnectorHeatingstring = str(actualCUEconnectorHeating);
        actualCUEHeatingstring = str(actualCUEHeating);
        actualmotorspeedstring = str(actualmotorspeed);

        hopperTempreadings.setText(actualhopperHeatingstring);
        hopperconnectorTempreadings.setText(actualhopperconnectorHeatingstring);
        CUEconnectorTempreadings.setText(actualCUEconnectorHeatingstring);
        CUETempreadings.setText(actualCUEHeatingstring);
        flowratereadings.setText(actualmotorspeedstring);

        // print the values (for debugging purposes only):
        println(actualhopperHeating + "\t" + actualhopperconnectorHeating + "\t" + actualCUEconnectorHeating + "\t" + actualCUEHeating + "\t" + actualmotorspeed);

        // Send a capital A to request new sensor readings:
        //myPort.write('A');
        // Reset serialCount:
        serialCount = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Arduino:

```
// Include the AccelStepper Library
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Define pin connections
const int dirPinSmall = 2;
const int stepPinSmall = 3;
const int SmallEnable = 6;

const int dirPinBig = 4;
const int stepPinBig = 5;
const int BigEnable = 7;

int SmallSpeed = 0;
int BigSpeed = 0;

// Define heating pad pins
const int PIN_RELAY_1 = 11;
const int PIN_RELAY_2 = 10;
const int PIN_RELAY_3 = 9;
const int PIN_RELAY_4 = 8;

//Thermistor Constants
const double B = 3434; //thermistor beta value
const double T0 = 22 + 273.15; //thermistor stock temp K
const double VIn = 5; //volts - input to voltage vivider

double RT_Z1; //omhs
double T_Z1;  //temp C
const int VOutPin_Z1 = A0; //Thermistor pin in
double VOut_Z1; //measured voltage in voltage divider
const double RS_Z4  = 9910; //ohms second resistor in voltage divider
const double RT0_Z1 = 11470; //thermistor stock resistance ohms

double RT_Z2; //omhs
double T_Z2;  //temp C
const int VOutPin_Z2 = A1; //Thermistor pin in
double VOut_Z2; //measured voltage in voltage divider
const double RS_Z3  = 9860; //ohms second resistor in voltage divider
const double RT0_Z2 = 12480; //thermistor stock resistance ohms

double RT_Z3; //omhs
double T_Z3;  //temp C
const int VOutPin_Z3 = A2; //Thermistor pin in
double VOut_Z3; //measured voltage in voltage divider
const double RS_Z2  = 9890; //ohms second resistor in voltage divider
const double RT0_Z3 = 12240; //thermistor stock resistance ohms

double RT_Z4; //omhs
double T_Z4;  //temp C
const int VOutPin_Z4 = A3; //Thermistor pin in
double VOut_Z4; //measured voltage in voltage divider
const double RS_Z1  = 9940; //ohms second resistor in voltage divider
const double RT0_Z4 = 11470; //thermistor stock resistance ohms

//Temp Varibels
int Z1_Temp  = 10;
int Z1_Range = 2;
int Z2_Temp  = 10;
int Z2_Range = 2;
int Z3_Temp  = 10;
int Z3_Range = 2;
int Z4_Temp  = 10;
int Z4_Range = 2;

//Time Trackers
unsigned long timeTracker = 0;
const long interval = 1000;

// Define motor interface type
#define motorInterfaceType 1

// Creates an instance for the stepper motors
AccelStepper myStepperSmall(motorInterfaceType, stepPinSmall, dirPinSmall);
AccelStepper myStepperBig(motorInterfaceType, stepPinBig, dirPinBig);

// Incoming serial byte
int inByte;

void setup() {

  // initialize the motor pins
  pinMode(SmallEnable, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BigEnable , OUTPUT);

  myStepperSmall.setMaxSpeed(750);
  myStepperSmall.setSpeed(SmallSpeed);

  myStepperBig.setMaxSpeed(1250);
  myStepperBig.setSpeed(BigSpeed);

  // initialize the heating pad pins
  pinMode(PIN_RELAY_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_RELAY_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_RELAY_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_RELAY_4, OUTPUT);

  // initialize the thermistor pins
  pinMode(VOutPin_Z1, INPUT);
  pinMode(VOutPin_Z2, INPUT);
  pinMode(VOutPin_Z3, INPUT);
  pinMode(VOutPin_Z4, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  
  establishContact();


}

void loop() {
  //tracks run time
  if(Serial.available() >= 5) {
    Z1_Temp = Serial.parseInt();
    Z2_Temp = Serial.parseInt();
    Z3_Temp = Serial.parseInt();
    Z4_Temp = Serial.parseInt();
    SmallSpeed = Serial.parseInt();

    Serial.read();
  
    unsigned long RunTime = millis();

    //Thermistors
    VOut_Z1 = (analogRead(VOutPin_Z1) * VIn) / 1023.0;
    RT_Z1 = (VIn / VOut_Z1) * RS_Z1 - RS_Z1;
    T_Z1 = (B / (log(RT_Z1 / RT0_Z1) + B / T0)) - 273.15;

    VOut_Z2 = (analogRead(VOutPin_Z2) * VIn) / 1023.0;
    RT_Z2 = (VIn / VOut_Z2) * RS_Z2 - RS_Z2;
    T_Z2 = (B / (log(RT_Z2 / RT0_Z2) + B / T0)) - 273.15;

    VOut_Z3 = (analogRead(VOutPin_Z3) * VIn) / 1023.0;
    RT_Z3 = (VIn / VOut_Z3) * RS_Z3 - RS_Z3;
    T_Z3 = (B / (log(RT_Z3 / RT0_Z3) + B / T0)) - 273.15;

    VOut_Z4 = (analogRead(VOutPin_Z4) * VIn) / 1023.0;
    RT_Z4 = (VIn / VOut_Z4) * RS_Z4 - RS_Z4;
    T_Z4 = (B / (log(RT_Z4 / RT0_Z4) + B / T0)) - 273.15;


    if (RunTime - timeTracker >= 1000) {
      timeTracker = RunTime;
      Serial.print(T_Z1);
      Serial.print(T_Z2);
      Serial.print(T_Z3);
      Serial.print(T_Z4);
    }

    Serial.print(SmallSpeed);

  }


  //Heating Pads------------------------------------------------------

  if (T_Z1 < Z1_Temp - Z1_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_1, HIGH);
  }
  if (T_Z1 > Z1_Temp + Z1_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_1, LOW);
  }

  if (T_Z2 < Z2_Temp - Z2_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_2, HIGH);
  }
  if (T_Z2 > Z2_Temp + Z2_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_2, LOW);
  }

  if (T_Z3 < Z3_Temp - Z3_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_3, HIGH);
  }
  if (T_Z3 > Z3_Temp + Z3_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_3, LOW);
  }

  if (T_Z4 < Z4_Temp - Z4_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_4, HIGH);
  }
  if (T_Z4 > Z4_Temp + Z4_Range) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY_4, LOW);
  }


  //Motors-------------------------------------------------------------
  // Motor enabeling
  if (SmallSpeed == 0) {
    digitalWrite(SmallEnable, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(SmallEnable, LOW);
  }

  if (BigSpeed == 0) {
    digitalWrite(BigEnable, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(BigEnable, LOW);
  }

  myStepperSmall.setSpeed(SmallSpeed);
  myStepperBig.setSpeed(BigSpeed);

  myStepperSmall.run();
  myStepperBig.run();

}

void establishContact() {
  while (Serial.available() <= 0) {
    Serial.println('A');
    delay(300);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck if you sent an array of slider values as opposed to sending individual strings from text fields.  Please consider the following demo which sends an array of five slider values to Arduino UNO which immediately reports the values that it received back to the Processing app.  Arduino code is also shown.

**Processing code:**

```
import controlP5.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
ControlP5 cp5;

int[] sliderVal = {30, 30, 30, 30, 300};

int slider0Value = sliderVal[0];
int slider1Value = sliderVal[1];
int slider2Value = sliderVal[2];
int slider3Value = sliderVal[3];
int slider4Value = sliderVal[4];

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  surface.setTitle("Data");
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  // slider value linked to variable 'sliderNumValue'
  cp5.addSlider("slider0Value")
    .setPosition(60, 50)
    .setHeight(24)
    .setCaptionLabel("Temp 0")
    .setRange(0, 100)
    ;

  cp5.addSlider("slider1Value")
    .setPosition(60, 90)
    .setHeight(24)
    .setCaptionLabel("Temp 1")
    .setRange(0, 100)
    ;

  cp5.addSlider("slider2Value")
    .setPosition(60, 130)
    .setHeight(24)
    .setCaptionLabel("Temp 2")
    .setRange(0, 100)
    ;

  cp5.addSlider("slider3Value")
    .setPosition(60, 170)
    .setHeight(24)
    .setCaptionLabel("Temp 3")
    .setRange(0, 100)
    ;

  cp5.addSlider("slider4Value")
    .setPosition(60, 210)
    .setHeight(24)
    .setCaptionLabel("Flow")
    .setRange(0, 1000)
    ;

  // Send_Data button
  cp5.addButton("Send_Data")
    .setPosition(220, 100)
    .setSize(100, 24)
    ;
  printArray(Serial.list());
  // Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[3], 9600);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
}

public void Send_Data() {
  println("Send_Data button hit.");
  sliderVal[0] = slider0Value;
  sliderVal[1] = slider1Value;
  sliderVal[2] = slider2Value;
  sliderVal[3] = slider3Value;
  sliderVal[4] = slider4Value;

  printArray(sliderVal);

  for (int i = 0; i < sliderVal.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      myPort.write("\n"); //So first value will show up
    }
    myPort.write(sliderVal[i]+"\n");
  }
}

void serialEvent(Serial p) {
  String inStr = p.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (inStr != null) {
    print("received: ", inStr);
  }  
}
```

**Arduino code:**

```
int temp0Val = 0;
int temp1Val = 0;
int temp2Val = 0;
int temp3Val = 0;
int flowVal = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println("#################");
    temp0Val = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(temp0Val);
    temp1Val = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(temp1Val);
    temp2Val = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(temp2Val);
    temp3Val = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println( temp3Val);
    flowVal = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(flowVal);
    Serial.println("=================");
  }
}
```